# IIS bindings - example.com and www.example.com

Tags: iis-7, binding

I simply want both example.com and www.example.com to go to the same website. Currently we have just added a binding to each. This creates a problem for WCF which then breaks because it says it can only accept one http address.

Is there a better way to configure a site to accept addresses with or without 'www'?

Comment: Please use `example.com` as an example domain name.  It is reserved for just that purpose, whereas someone might (does, actually) own the domain used in your question.

Answer (score 0):

this has to be changed in the dns using a host or a record.

Comment: It is set up to accept both in the dns settings. I just need to configure both in the bindings so I can hit a service from either address.

Comment: in that case [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(WS.10).aspx) this might help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be hosting a site on the root domain. Better approach here is to redirect traffic to the root (.example.com) to the correct site (www.example.com) using an HTTP 302.

The WCF service should only receive traffic on its single binding. Use DNS, HTTP redirection, or some Traffic management application/appliance to get traffic from multiple points to the correct one.